# how to use LinearGradient for react tab navigator tabs

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-navigation

I have a react `tabnavigator`  which i used it from `ReactNavigation(v2)` component:

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({

  Nearest: {
    screen: Nearest, navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'myprofile'
    }
  },

  Recomanded: {
    screen: Recomanded, navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'recomanded'
    }
  },
  Home: {
    screen: Hotest, navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'hotest'
    }
  },
},
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 12,
         fontFamily:"IRANSans"
      },
      tabStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#ef6102',

      }
    }

  }
);
```

now i want to use **linear gradient** for Tabs color but i couldn't find any way to do it!...how its possible ? how can i take the tabs inside this tag:

```
  <LinearGradient  colors={['#EF7D2F', '#C8191A']}>..here..</LinearGradient>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add custom view for your tab by using `tabBarCompontent`:

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({

  Nearest: {
    screen: Nearest, navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'myprofile'
    }
  },

  Recomanded: {
    screen: Recomanded, navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'recomanded'
    }
  },
  Home: {
    screen: Hotest, navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'hotest'
    }
  },
},
  {
    tabBarComponent:(props)=>{
               return(<TabBar {...props}></TabBar>)},<<<<<<<look here<<<<<<<<

    tabBarOptions: {
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 12,
         fontFamily:"IRANSans"
      },
      tabStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#ef6102',

      }
    }

  }
);
```

for example TabBar is a component like this:

```
const TabBar=(props)=> {
        return (
           <LinearGradient  colors={['#EF7D2F', '#C8191A']}>..here.. 
            </LinearGradient>
        );


}
```

you can use [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator) as a reference